# Where to get item styles for StackedSplineArea and StepAreaSeries?

Tags: silverlight, charts, telerik

I am creating an app with teleriks silverlight controls.
I had a problem with chart coloring. It is adding some opacity and gradients to charts.
It can be fixed by changing item style from SeriesDefinition.
For Bar charts I found template by googling and changed it as needed, but I can't find templates for  StackedSplineArea and StepAreaSeries.
Where can I find this templates?
I tried with blend, but it does not give any template.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
To disable colour opacity you need to set `PaletteBrushesUseSolidColors` property of `RadChart` to `true`. In my case this was enought and there is no need for templates.